# How to avoid inserting undefined in MySQL using nodejs and reactjs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

Is there a way to stop inserting an undefined value in MYSQL using reactjs?

so here is the code.

```
  const regex = /.*([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{11}).*/gi;

  if (postData.video_id) {
    postData.video_id = postData.video_id.replace(regex, "$1");
  }
```

and it keeps submitting undefined in the database, I need to make it optional either with value or empty, it is up to the user.

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

the data might do not match with the regex, so
validate the replace expression before assign it to `postData.video_id` :

```js
  const regex = /.*([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{11}).*/gi;

  if (postData.video_id) {
    const videoId = postData.video_id.replace(regex, "$1");
    if(videoId) postData.video_id = videoId;
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, i tried what you said, but still it didn't work